# Character Encoding in Sending Email and PHP

Tags: php, validation, character-encoding, character

I have a simple contact page that sends email with contact data with code below. But I can not read any of them because the characters are not readable. Based on my website content i guess these emails are Arabic. I tried so many character encoding in my browser view but the problem still exists. For example,Thats a part of one email :Ø§Ø­Ù…Ø¯Ù¾ÙˆØ±
I want to know whats wrong with that code, How I can fix it  and how I can read the texts from previous emails?

```
<?php

$EmailFrom = "info@example.com";
$EmailTo = "info@example.com";
$Subject = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['City'])); 
$Name = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['Name'])); 
$Tel = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['Tel'])); 
$Email = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['Email'])); 
$Message = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['Message'])); 

// validation
$validationOK=true;
if (!$validationOK) {
  print "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=error.htm\">";
  exit;
}

// prepare email body text
$Body = "";
$Body .= "Name: ";
$Body .= $Name;
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "Tel: ";
$Body .= $Tel;
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "Email: ";
$Body .= $Email;
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "Message: ";
$Body .= $Message;
$Body .= "\n";

// send email 
$success = mail($EmailTo, $Subject, $Body, "From: <$EmailFrom>");

// redirect to success page 
if ($success){
  print "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=contactthanks.php\">";
}
else{
  print "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=error.htm\">";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
$header = "From: <$EmailFrom> \r\n";
$header .= "MIME-Version: 1.0 \r\n";
$header .= "Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8";

$success = mail($EmailTo, $Subject, $Body, $header );
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't go with your own solutions to compose and send email, you are likely to get it wrong. Use some email class, for example [PHPMailer](http://pear.php.net/package/Mail_Mime/). There just set CharSet property:

```
$mailer = new PHPMailer();
$mailer->CharSet = 'utf-8';
```

Or [swiftmailer][2], or [Pear's Mail Mime](http://pear.php.net/package/Mail_Mime/)